# Doesn't or don't in "watercolor or any type of water-based paint {doesn't/don't} work"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Watercolor or any type of water-based paint **doesn't** work
> Watercolor or any type of water-based paint **don't** work

Is it doesn't or don't? Plural or singular?

Answer (score 2):

The use of **or** means that you treat the subjects individually.

> **Cake** ***or*** **pie** **sounds** good.  [Two singular subjects.]
>   **Cake** ***and*** **pie** **sound** good.  [One combined plural subject.]

In your example sentence, you're lucky that you are also using **any**, because **any** takes a singular form:

1.(**Watercolor**) **doesn't** work.
2.(**Any type of watercolor**) **doesn't** work.

Therefore, you can combine the two singular subjects with the **or** conjunction and still use a singular verb:

> ✔ **Watercolor** ***or*** **any type of water-based paint** **doesn't** work.

---

But had you used *all types*, for instance, you'd be in trouble:

1.(**Watercolor**) **doesn't** work.
2.(**All types of watercolor**) **don't** work.

In this case, the first subject is singular, so it uses a singular verb. However, the second subject is plural, so it uses a plural verb. Whichever verb form you chose with the **or** conjunction would fail to be grammatical.

> ✘ **Watercolor** ***or*** **all types of water-based paint** **doesn't** work.
>   → ✘ All types of watercolor **doesn't** work.
>
> ✘ **Watercolor** ***or*** **all types of water-based paint** **don't** work.
>   → ✘ Watercolour **don't** work.

The only way to get the combined sentence to work with *all types* would be to replace **or** with **and**, turning it into a combined plural subject:

> ✔ **Watercolor** ***and*** **all types of water-based paint** **don't** work.

---

Incidentally, the same is true if you turn *watercolor* into *watercolors*, making the first subject plural, but leaving the second subject singular:

> ✘ **Watercolors** ***or*** **any type of water-based paint** **don't** work.
>   → ✘ **Any type of water-based paint** **don't** work.

As before, when there are mixed singular and plural subjects, it can only be fixed by using **and** rather than **or**, making it a combined plural subject:

> ✔ **Watercolors** ***and*** **any type of water-based paint** **don't** work.