# I use acrylic paint/paints

Tags: grammar, word-choice, singular-vs-plural, idiomatic-language

> Is it oil paintings?
>
> No, I use acrylic paint/paints.

Should paint be in plural here or what is idiomatic/makes more sense? I have seen both used.

Comment: I also see/hear _I use acrylics_.

Comment: See [Doesn't or don't in "watercolor or any type of water-based paint {doesn't/don't} work"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205084/doesnt-or-dont-in-watercolor-or-any-type-of-water-based-paint-doesnt-dont), where one of the answers transparently switches between examples featuring singular (uncountable, mass-noun) ***watercolor*** and the *countable* form ***watercolors*** (which could be seen as "short for" the more obviously countable form *watercolor **paints***). You've seen both used because they ***are*** - and in your exact context it's entirely a stylistic choice.

Comment: ..but you'd rarely hear a native speaker ask *Is it oil paintings?* In almost all contexts, it's ***Are they** oil paintings?*

Comment: When talking about painting a wall or house you would say "I used red paint" or "I used emulsion paint". If talking about art, you're more likely to use the plural, but could still use the singular. The plural has more artistic connotations. To me, the plural suggests you have your own valued collection of tubes of oil or acrylic paint (which would be referred to as "my paints") rather than just viewing paint as a tool or medium that you don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

See [Doesn't or don't in "watercolor or any type of water-based paint {doesn't/don't} work](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205084/doesnt-or-dont-in-watercolor-or-any-type-of-water-based-paint-doesnt-dont)", where one of the answers transparently switches between examples featuring singular (uncountable, mass-noun) **watercolor** and the countable form **watercolors** (which could be seen as "short for" the more obviously countable form **watercolor paints**). You've seen both used because they are - and in your exact context it's entirely a stylistic choice, but you'd rarely hear a native speaker ask "Is it oil paintings?" In almost all contexts, it's "**Are they** oil paintings?"

When talking about painting a wall or house you would say "I used red paint" or "I used emulsion paint". If talking about art, you're more likely to use the plural, but could still use the singular. The plural has more artistic connotations. To me, the plural suggests you have your own valued collection of tubes of oil or acrylic paint (which would be referred to as "my paints") rather than just viewing paint as a tool or medium that you don't care about.